# Can not get default store view in Admin

Tags: admin, store-view

We recently moved to a new server and on our new server we can not choose the default config. It reverts to the main store view and won't let me change my default items without unchecking the box.

There is only one store view and one website.

Here are the steps we took in changing servers

1) Rackspace setup complete new server
2) 3rd party security company setup Apache
3) We moved the content folder to new server

The database has always been on it's own server so we did not touch that.

The security company moved much of the main htaccess commands into the vhost file, they then locked the vhost file so only they can see it. (Rackspace told me this on the phone)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swap out your database name, and try running this against your database*

```
USE `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

*Please backup these tables before making any changes.

Comment: The only thing we changed was servers, we did not backup and restore the database so I am not sure how the default store would have changed?